# How do I concatenate this CSS background image url correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following CSS for a banner like image (external CSS file):

```
.banner {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba( 255, 255, 252, 0.8 )), url('banners/imageA.jpg');
}
```

and I have a function that changes the background image but also uses the parameter for other things.

```
function bannerchange(element)    {
    document.getElementById('banner').style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.8 )), url('banners' + element + .jpg\')";
    document.getElementById('bannertext').innerHTML = element;
    document.getElementById('infotext').src = 'infotexts/' + element + '.txt';
```

I have no trouble setting the new background image by static url

```
 document.getElementById('banner').style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.8 )), url(banners/element.jpg)";
```

However any combination of concatenations I tried fail to load the image correctly with the function parameter, e.g.

```
url('banners/' + element + '.jpg')";
```

and variations.

What is the correct way to use this? I give up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use double quotes as follows:

```
document.getElementById('banner').style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.8 )), url(banners/" + element + ".jpg)";
```